# How do I dynamically add fragments to start of ViewPager as user reaches the end of the ViewPager?

Tags: java, android, dynamic, android-viewpager, fragmentstatepageradapter

I currently have a basic `ViewPager` that utilizes a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` to initialize fragments.

This `ViewPager` starts at the end and scrolls backwards (i.e. scrolls to the left).

As the user nears the start of the `ViewPager`'s list, I want there to be more items added to the start of the adapter's list programmatically, essentially creating an infinitely scrollable `ViewPager` (going left) without disrupting the user's experience (i.e. not reloading their current fragment as the ViewPager has fragments added on to it). However, I am unable to accomplish this.

Currently, I am detecting when my adapter's `getItem()` function passes a position of 0, populating the start of the list the adapter uses with more items, and then calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`. However, what happens is that the fragments at position 1 (which triggers the `getItem()` call as soon as it comes into focus) and 0 remain at the start of the `ViewPager` and the new fragments are loaded all out of order.

Here is my `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`:

```
class WeekyMoodFragmentAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private final int NUM_WEEKS_TO_INITIALIZE = 4;
    private final List<Long> timestampList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final ViewPager mViewPager;

    WeekyMoodFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager, ViewPager viewPager) {
        super(fragmentManager);

        mViewPager = viewPager;
        initializeTimestampList();
    }

    private void initializeTimestampList() {

        DateTime mondayOfThisWeek = new DateTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
        while (mondayOfThisWeek.getDayOfWeek() != DateTimeConstants.MONDAY) {
            mondayOfThisWeek = new DateTime(mondayOfThisWeek.getMillis()
                    - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(DateTimeConstants.HOURS_PER_DAY));
        }

        long weekStartMS = mondayOfThisWeek.withTimeAtStartOfDay().getMillis()
                - TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(DateTimeConstants.DAYS_PER_WEEK * NUM_WEEKS_TO_INITIALIZE);

        addTimestampsToList(weekStartMS);
    }

    private void addTimestampsToList(long weekStartMS) {
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_WEEKS_TO_INITIALIZE; ++i) {
            weekStartMS += TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(DateTimeConstants.DAYS_PER_WEEK);

            timestampList.add(i, weekStartMS);
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = WeeklyMoodFragment.newInstance(timestampList.get(position));
        if (position == 0) {
            addTimestampsToList(timestampList.get(position)
                    - TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis
                    (DateTimeConstants.DAYS_PER_WEEK * (NUM_WEEKS_TO_INITIALIZE+1)));
        }
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return timestampList.size();
    }
}
```

And how I initialize my `ViewPager`:

```
ViewPager moodViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.weeklyMoodViewPager);

moodViewPager.setAdapter(new WeekyMoodFragmentAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
moodViewPager.setCurrentItem(moodViewPager.getAdapter().getCount());
```

Answer (score 0):

have you considered a bit hacky way with `getCount()` returning `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and `newInstance` created from `timestampList.get(position%timestampList.size())`? and set initial page `setCurrentItem` as `Integer.MAX_VALUE/2` or nearest appriopiate

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return WeeklyMoodFragment.newInstance(
        timestampList.get(position % timestampList.size()));
        //                         ^  here important
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
}

    ...

moodViewPager.setCurrentItem(Integer.MAX_VALUE/2);
//or 
WeekyMoodFragmentAdapteradapter = new WeekyMoodFragmentAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
moodViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
//dividing integers will round
int roundedCount = (Integer.MAX_VALUE/2) / adapter.getCount();
moodViewPager.setCurrentItem(roundedCount * adapter.getCount())
```